# Extend a line through 3 points matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

Im just trying to draw a line through the following points in matlab. Currently the line extends only to the points. I need to to extend and intercept the x axis. The code is below

```
A = [209.45 198.066 162.759];
B = [1.805 1.637 1.115]; 
plot(A,B,'*');
axis([0 210 0 2]);
hold on
line(A,B)
hold off
```

Comment: Take a look at `interp1`. Are you familiar with anonymous functions? You don't necessarily need one, but it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to augment your points with a corresponding `y==0` point, I suggest using `interp1` to obtain the `x`-intercept:

```
A = [209.45 198.066 162.759];
B = [1.805 1.637 1.115];

x0 = interp1(B,A,0,'linear','extrap'); %extrapolate (y,x) at y==0 to get x0
[newA, inds] = sort([x0 A]); %insert x0 where it belongs
newB = [0 B];
newB = newB(inds); %keep the same order with B

plot(A,B,'b*',newA,newB,'b-');
```

This will use `interp1` to perform a linear interpolant, with extrapolation switched on. By interpolating `(B,A)` pairs, we in effect invert your linear function.

Next we add the `(x0,0)` point to the data, but since matlab draws lines in the order of the points, we have to `sort` the vector according to `x` component. The sorting order is then used to keep the same order in the extended `B` vector.

Finally the line is plotted. I made use of `plot` with a `linespec` of `'-'` to draw the line in the same command as the points themselves. If it doesn't bother you that the `(x0,0)` point is also indicated, you can plot both markers and lines together using `plot(newA,newB,'*-');` which ensures that the colors match up (in the above code I manually set the same blue colour on both plots).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the description as well. Really helped me understand